# Duplicates items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Working on a ASP.Net application in Visual Studio 2019. Occasionally when I build one of my solutions I get this error

> The item "FeatureTests\Accrediation\AccessAccreditationPage.feature.cs" was specified more than once in > the "Sources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter.

I can't seem to find any rhyme or reason as to what triggers it. Last time it happened after Merging a branch, this time it happened after applying some db scripts.

I've looked in the csproj file of the solution and no such duplicate is found.

The only solution that I have is to delete my repo and reclone it.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I can think of a couple of scenarios:

You said the "I've looked in the csproj file of the solution and no such duplicate is found.", you mean the csproj of this particular project that is failing to build, right?

Also, have you checked that the csproj does not contain duplicates in both branches?
What if a merge commit has recreated the duplicated entry?

Comment: @EmilianoJavierGonzález Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, yes to both those questions.

Comment: Cool, I'd try two other things, one is to enable "Show all files" option in solution explorer and search for the file, sometimes it shows up two times but one is kind grayed. And secondly, you've mentioned to recreate the repo, before doing that I can think of two things, git checkout <<SomeCommitWhenItWorked>> and see the differences, and second, git clean -f -x. If I think of something else I'll let you know! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I didn't find any duplicates in the csproj file of my solution. However, the error did go away when I discarded my changes to the csproj file.

Comment: looks more like a comment